# France, how long does a landlord have to give back caution if renovation are not the tenant's fault

Tags: landlord, france

I've recently moved out from my old place.
After talking with my landlord after checking the state of the premise, he told me that he was gonna give me back my caution in a period of two month.

At the time I did'nt think much, but after reading a bit about the law, most specificaly the [Alur law](https://droit-finances.commentcamarche.com/faq/25450-loi-alur-les-nouvelles-mesures) I've realised that, since the state of premise was identical (actually it was much better) when we left the premise as when we entered it, he should give us the caution back in a period of one month.

Now I think he plans on giving us the caution back in a period of two month because there is renovation to be done on the premise, but the renovation is not due to our (the tenants) actions, but problem unrelated to us. Problem such as the ventilation not working, one of our wall being soaked in water due to a pipe being pierced by the precedent tenant of the neighboring appartment, as well as water damage due to an appartment on top of our old one.

So here is my question :

Does a landlord have the right to witheld the caution for two month, because of damages wich were not cause by the tenants? (Note that only answer concerning the french law interests me).

Comment: Did you ask the real estate